# Parse Won't Save Installation, Error: badge must be a non-negative integer

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

My problem seems to be almost identical to this one, which was never solved:

https://www.parse.com/questions/installation-not-created

It started when I deleted all the installations from the Parse data browser (bad idea, I know that now). The problem now is that it won't save any new installations from one of my (real) test devices, presumably because of this confusing error:

```
Error: badge must be a non-negative integer: -3 (Code: 111, Version: 1.2.20)
```

This occurs on a fresh installation when I have yet to do anything to the badge number. To make it even more complicated, Parse *will* save installations from other (real) devices and the simulator. For reference, this is how I am attempting to save installations in my AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I still don't know why this error occurred, but the solution seemed to be inserting the following line of code and then removing it after installation:

```
[[PFInstallation currentInstallation] setBadge:0];
```